# Recursion in Tkinter and IDLE

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

I am currently trying some ttk.tkinter in Python 3.6 but I encounter a strange issue when using a recursive function handling lists and dictionaries in the interpreter vs. using it within tkinter. While the function works as intended in the interpreter for nested lists, the same function returns none instead of the value in a tkinter label.

```
    complexList = {'1' : {'2': '3', 'tg': '7', 'prop': ['4', '5', '9', {'v':['d', 't']}]}}

def recurse2(item, obj):
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if item == k:
            return k, v
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                if isinstance(i, str):
                    if item == i:
                        return (k, i)
                elif isinstance (i, dict):
                    var = i
                    return dictrecurse2(k, item, var)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            var = v
            return dictrecurse2(k, item, var)


def dictrecurse2(k, item, var):
    for sk, sv in var.items(): 
        if item == sk:                    
            return k, sk, sv
        elif item == sv:                    
            return k, sk, sv
        else:
            return recurse2(item, var)
```

(interpreter)

```
print(recurse2('v', complexList))
```

yields:

```
('prop', 'v', ['d', 't'])
```

Which is by and large intended. However for the label (function called by button)

```
searchitem = StringVar()
output  = StringVar()
def search():
    output.set(recurse2(searchitem.get(), complexList))
l = ttk.Label(root, textvariable = output)
l.grid(column =1, row =1)
startButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Start", command = search)
startButton.grid(column =1, row = 2)
entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = searchitem)
entry.grid(column =1, row =3)
```

The label shows "none".
Is there something obvious that I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

output.set(recurse2('1', complexList))

works but

```
output.set(recurse2('v', complexList))
```

does not

Comment: write `global searchitem`,  `global complexList` and `global output` inside your function `search()`

Comment: Nope does not work. It does work neither with 'v' as argument: output.set(recurse2('v', complexList)) still returns 'none'

Comment: Thanks mate, but that still does not work: output.set(recurse2('1', complexList)) works perfectly fine without global variables

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly for me. A `None` would be returned if you entered a value that is not found, for instance if you entered a capital "V", added a space, or pushed the Start button without entering a value into the Entry box. You could add `return "not found"` as the last line of "recurse2" if you wanted a more meaning full output.

Comment: I tried you program with Python 3.5 and was running just fine. You obviously  have to enter something that can be found into your Entry. If you leave it empty, it returns the same as `recurse2('', complexList)`, which returns None.

Comment: Tried it here too, works fine.

Comment: You might try double-checking that the `recurse2` and `dictrecurse2` you're running in the interpreter are exactly the same as the ones in your GUI script.

Comment: They should be: both of them are in the same function file imported... it should be in essence the same function: output.set(recurse2('v', complexList)) still yields a "none" label with text = output ... which works for all non-List instances. To be clear: It works perfectly fine outside of tkinter.

Comment: Well, it works perfectly fine inside Tkinter for us. Please turn your posted code into a [mcve], or we won't be able to find the issue.

Comment: Ok, this is very odd, I had a slightly different complexList (with another dict as value.) This seems to be the problem. With complexList = {'1' : {'2': '3', 'tg': {'tz':'rf'}, 'prop': ['4', '5', '9', {'v':['d', 't']}]}} this causes an issue for the recurse function when reading the list. At least I am getting at the root of the problem, which is something. Not sure however how to fix this. Thanks however, if I wouldn't have know that it worked for you, I would be still scratching my head.

Comment: Ok, while the recursive function may run arbritrarily deep, iterating over a dictionary not containing the searchitem aborts the whole thing (and returns none). How do I keep that from happening? While my MWE: `def basicrecurse(searchitem, obj):                
    for k,v in obj.items():
        if searchitem == v:
            print(k, v)
        elif searchitem == k:
            print (k,v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            basicrecurse(searchitem, v)` iterates over each nested dictionary, it also returns none. Also, it does not work with lists

Comment: Thanks, issue is resolved! The main problem was bad use of return statements. I now know better and it works like a charm!